# Javascript Object Constructor with DOM

Tags: javascript

I have recently started learning Javascript. I got stuck with a problem that I encountered. I wanted to create an Object using Object Constructor that generates a DOM Element. Then I have written a method to append it to a parent DOM Element using the parent's ID. Something went wrong and I didn't manage to solve the problem alone. That's why I am asking for your help. Bellow, you can find the code that I've written:

```
var Model = function () {
   var mdl = document.createElement("div");
   this.append = function (parent) {
      document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(mdl);
   };

   return this.mdl;

}

// And then Object init 
var House = new Model();
House.append("map");
```

This is the code I have written so far. I do not know where the problem might be. The error message I get in the console is: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.

I am waiting for your answer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there an element with `map` id in your page? Also, `this.mdl` is undefined, there is no point in returning it

Comment: You don't need to return `this.mdl` from the constructor as well

Comment: You don't need to return the html element from the class constructor. Also, as a side not, I suggest to use let instead of var.

Answer (score 0):

You should not return anything from the class, because if you return html element, it won't be an object of your class anymore. and 'append' is a default function that's why it's not returning error.

```js
var Model = function () {
   this.mdl = document.createElement("div");
   this.append = function (parent) {
      document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(this.mdl);
   };
}

// And then Object init 
var house = new Model();
house.append("map");
```

```html
<div id="map">

</div>
```